# Why am I unable to register multiple interfaces to a single type?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, autofac, .net-6.0

I am trying to register these types, so that no matter which of the 2 interfaces I inject within a particular scope, the same object instance will always be returned

Interfaces

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity, TEntityId> 
    where TEntity : DomainEntity<TEntityId>, IAggregateRoot 
    where TEntityId: notnull
```

and

```
public interface IEagerRepository<TEntity, TEntityId> : IRepository<TEntity, TEntityId>
    where TEntity: DomainEntity<TEntityId>, IAggregateRoot
    where TEntityId: notnull
```

and the type which should always be returned:

```
public class Repository<TEntity, TEntityId>
    : BaseRepository<DomainContext, TEntity, TEntityId> // BaseRepository implements IRepository
    , IEagerRepository<TEntity, TEntityId>
    where TEntity: DomainEntity<TEntityId>, IAggregateRoot
    where TEntityId: notnull
```

But I can't seem to get it to work.

I have tried registering them both from `IServiceCollection`:

```
services.AddScoped(typeof(IRepository<,>), typeof(Repository<,>));
services.AddScoped(typeof(IEagerRepository<,>), x => x.GetRequiredService(typeof(IRepository<,>)));
```

But I get this autofac error when at the point of injecting `IEagerRepository`

> cannot resolve paramater IEagerREpository

and when I simply register both as `AsScoped` - each injection returns a different instance of `Repository` (as expected)

I tried the following using autofac's `ContainerBuilder`:

```
autofacContainerBuilder
    .RegisterType(typeof(Repository<,>))
    .As(typeof(IRepository<,>))
    .As(typeof(IEagerRepository<,>))
    .AsImplementedInterfaces()
    .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

But I get this stupid exception on startup:

> System.ArgumentException: 'The type 'Repository`2[TEntity,TEntityId]' is not assignable to service 'IRepository`2'.'

I even tried explicitly adding  `: IRepository` to the `Repository` implementation, but the error is the same

Can anyone tell what is wrong?

Comment: Seems like you'd need to register the more derived type `IEagerRepository` first then register the less derived type `IRepository` to return the more derived type.

Comment: Set a breakpoint inside your `x => x.GetRequiredService` method and tell us what the runtime types are.

Comment: @Dai when placing a breakpoint inside that lambda it never gets hit - exception `cannot resolve paramter IEagerRepository` is thrown first

Answer (score 2):

Right after posting the question, I found that I can overcome this by registering like so:

```
autofacContainerBuilder
    .RegisterGeneric(typeof(Repository<,>))
    .As(typeof(IRepository<,>))
    .As(typeof(IEagerRepository<,>))
    .AsImplementedInterfaces()
    .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

The difference being a call to `RegisterGeneric` rather than `RegisterType`